# Apply style to first element in a row of similar elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following list (the numbers are just for reference)

```
<div class="A">alpha1</div>
<div class="B">alpha2</div>
<div class="A">alpha3</div>
<div class="A">alpha4</div>
<div class="A">alpha5</div>
<div class="B">alpha6</div>
<div class="A">alpha7</div>
```

I want to apply one style to DIVS 1, 3 and 7, because they are the first of their class (A) in a row of elements of the same class. Is there a pseudo element / magic I can use for that? Something like (inventing)

```
not(.A) & .A {color:red} -> if class is A and it is not preceded by an A
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the `:not()` pseudo-class with an adjacent sibling combinator `+` to match an `.A` that is not immediately preceded by an `.A`:

```
:not(.A) + .A
```

You'll also need to use `:first-child` to select the very first `.A` element since it's not preceded by anything:

```
.A:first-child
```

Combine them, and you have:

```
:not(.A) + .A, .A:first-child { color: red; }
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2yveP)

Comment: This looks like a correct CSS solution. This is defiantly what you should do if you don't have to support older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a cross browser solution using JavaScript:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/YhvGw/

```
function applyStyleToFirstDiv(className, styleAttr, val,baseSelector) {
    //Allow to specify a base element to search in
    if(baseSelector == null){
        baseSelector = document    
    }
    var divElements = baseSelector.getElementsByTagName("div"),
        len = divElements.length;
    var prevWas = false,currentIs;
    // Go through all the divs
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var cur = divElements[i];
        var classes = cur.className.split(" ");
        currentIs = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
            //If you find a matching class
            if (classes[j] === className) {
                currentIs = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //If the current one matches, and the last one didn't, apply the style, otherwise don't
        if(currentIs && !prevWas){
            cur.style[styleAttr] = val;    
        }
        prevWas = currentIs;

    }
}
//usage sample
applyStyleToFirstDiv("A","color","yellow");
```

Comment: That only works if he knows which children need the style beforehand. I think what he really wants to do is have the browser figure that out itself so that it doesn't have to be adjusted if the content changes.

Comment: This also only selects the very first child, and not the first in a cluster.

Comment: @BoltClock oh wait, right you are, I just understood the question. Fix coming right up

Comment: I posted an answer too. It's actually pretty simple if browser support is a non-issue, but I'd like to see what you can come up with using JS since it can't easily be done using pure CSS2 selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock I've added a JavaScript solution. Your pure CSS one seems fine.

Comment: I was not clear enough... I needed a CSS based solution. THank you very much for your time!

Comment: @user1345913 You don't have to apologize, I like coding :) Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
div:not(.A) + .A, .A:first-of-type{
color:red;
}
```