# Can I select an element that's not immediately after another, e.g. :not(.foo + .bar)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to have a `:not(.foo + .bar)` selector? Or do I have to use a separate selector to cancel out the effects of `.foo + .bar`?

Comment: `:not` only takes simple selectors...and that isn't one.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you have 3 sibling elements and want to change the styles of one of them? Can we see your html?

Comment: The question is self-explanatory. The asker wants to match any .bar that is not .foo + .bar. If you need HTML to understand what .foo + .bar means, then you need to do some basic research on CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that `:not(.foo + .bar)` is valid in [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation), and [implementations are on their way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993727/not-selector-not-behaving-the-same-between-safari-and-chrome-firefox/35993791#35993791). Having said that, due to the nature of the adjacent sibling combinator `+` (and similarly the child combinator `>`), there is a Selectors 3 equivalent, although you will need a list of up to three complex selectors:

```
:first-child, :not(.foo) + *, .foo + :not(.bar)
```

But this is a direct conversion that accounts for elements that are not `.bar`. More likely, you just want to match any `.bar` that's not directly preceded by a `.foo`. In that case, it gets even simpler:

```
.bar:first-child, :not(.foo) + .bar
```

And you can pick and choose further depending on your needs:

- If not being preceded by a `.foo` means `.bar` becomes the first child, you can just use `.bar:first-child`.
- If `.bar` is guaranteed to have a preceding sibling, you can just use `:not(.foo) + .bar`.

If you need to account for both possibilities, then listing both as shown above will do just fine.

Note that the `.foo` and `.bar` selectors don't necessarily have to be different. You can match any `.bar` that's not immediately preceded by *another `.bar`* with the [exact same technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678857/apply-style-to-first-element-in-a-row-of-similar-elements/16678939#16678939).